# Image size issue with parallax effect

Tags: html, css

I am having problem with background-attachment:fixed. When I use this property then the image size gets bigger.

How can I keep the image size in normal ratio but using parallax effect.

Code:

```
<div class="full_width full-bg">
    <div class="contact-banner ratio4_1"></div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:3rem;"></div>
<div class="full_width full-bg">
    <div class="contact-banner ratio4_1 parallax"></div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/w7rxv5xj/embedded/result/

Editor: http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/w7rxv5xj/

I want to keep the image size as first one but would like to apply parallax effect.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set `background-size: 100% auto` for `.parallax` class

```
.parallax {
   background-attachment:fixed;
   background-size: 100% auto;
 }
```

---

Fork: http://jsfiddle.net/r7oyxL92/

Comment: I tried using 100% auto but in that case there are some white space left at the bottom and when you scroll then you can see the white space at the top of the container. But if I use background size cover then I don't see the white space but the image seems to be larger.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. The banner image itself was short in height. So stupid I am. Thank you so much for your help.